# Parameter error with mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have found this a sticky problem, since running into it. Would love to know whether you can help me spot the error in posting this form to a database, it connect but a parameters error keeps reoccurring.

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db("members");


    if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){

         $f_name = $_POST['first_name'];
         $l_name = $_POST['last_name'];
         $user_email = $_POST['email'];



         $query = "INSERT into members (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('$f_name','$l_name','$user_email')";

         if (!mysqli_query ($conn,$sqlinsert)) {

            die('error inserting new record');


          } // end of nested if state

          $newrecord = "1 record added success";


    } // end of 1st if state
```

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving.  I do notice that your variable is called `$query` but you are calling `mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)` instead - `$sqlinsert` is not defined here. See also [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and the examples there on using `prepare()/bind_param()/execute()` with MySQLi to improve security against injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!mysqli_query ($conn, $sqlinsert)) {
```

Should be

```
 if (!mysqli_query ($conn, $query)) {
```

Don't see anything wrong with the query although you should note it'll be vulnerable to SQL injections (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)).

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your time sincerely!